# PIL: cannot identify image file

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to open an image with PIL and get a thumbnail of it.
The problem is that PIL says to me:

> cannot identify image file

First of all, I download the image from an S3 bucket, then I saved it to the `/tmp/` directory of a AWS Lambda. I'm sure that the file exists because I printed it through `os.walk()` function.
I also tried passing directly the path of the file.

This is the code snippet:

```
bucket.download_file(bucket_key, '/tmp/' + 'michelin.png')
with open('/tmp/michelin.png', 'rb') as f:
    im = Image.open(f)
```

Any ideas to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to declare a path variable e.g. `path = path = os.path.join('/tmp/'+'michelin.png')`and just use `im = Image.open(path)`

Comment: Doesn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to open the file in advance. PIL.Image.open will do that from within.
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html

`Image.open('/tmp/michelin.png')`

Comment: I open file in advance because I read that it's possible that a file just created can't be reached immediately in a read operation.
However, your solution didn't work, I've already tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.
I had to use

```
img_file_s3 = s3.meta.client.download_file(bucket_name, bucket_key + 'michelin.png', '/tmp/michelin.png')
```

instead of

```
bucket.download_file(bucket_key, '/tmp/' + 'michelin.png')
```